# TABLESWITCH Performance Increase?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, switch-statement

Say I have the following `switch` statement:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 0: ...; return ...;
    case 1: ...; return ...;
    case 2: ...; return ...;
    case 400: ...; return ...;
    case 401: ...; return ...;
    case 402: ...; return ...;
}
```

Since the gaps are too large for the compiler to generate a reasonable `TABLESWITCH` (`O(1)` complexity) instruction here, it uses a `LOOKUPSWITCH` (`O(log n)` complexity). Would it be possible to increase the performance of this code by splitting the `switch` into two like this:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 0: ...; return ...;
    case 1: ...; return ...;
    case 2: ...; return ...;
}

switch (i)
{
    case 400: ...; return ...;
    case 401: ...; return ...;
    case 402: ...; return ...;
}
```

This would cause the compiler to generate two `TABLESWITCH` instead of one `LOOKUPSWITCH`.

Comment: 1) [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) (Donald Knuth). 2) Why not simply use a map?

Comment: Because a map requires boxing, which is far too inefficient for my needs. Also, my use case is performance critical, so I can happily live with premature optimizations.

Comment: So why not use an array? Array lookup is certainly cheaper than method dispatch. I'm very skeptical that your claims are supported by evidence if you haven't noticed this in profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not spend much time trying to optimize the bytecode. The bytecode does not necessarily reflect the performance of JIT-compiled methods. Why don't you take [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and check the actual performance of both cases yourself?

In fact, HotSpot C2 compiler treats `tableswitch` and `lookupswitch` in a similar way, and it takes care of `lookupswitch` that has sequential labels with gaps very well.

Both cases are translated into a sequence of compare and conditional jump instructions in a binary search-like manner and work almost identically performance-wise.

Comment: Alright, did the tests myself: Average of 1000 * 1000000 switch instructions on a random integer 0..199, matching regions 0..10 and 100..110: Single Switch 14538.13 ms, Separated Switch 15209.492 ms

Comment: @Clashsoft The problem with this benchmark is the predictability. With a random input, the branching is unpredictable and some numerical preprocessing (e.g., transforming 400+x into 3+x) may be beneficial. With a real input the result may differ completely.